# Problem installing patterns & practices SharePoint Guidance

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Trouble of setupt the Partner Portal.I got the System.NotImplementedException when I run the setup script , can someone shine some light on this?

I am running the VSeWSS using local machine administrator account.

18:05:14.24 call 02_CreateContosoServices.bat

18:05:24.06 call 03a_BuildSolutions.bat

18:05:37.51 call 03b_PackageSolutions.bat

2010/01/03 17:45:27 Error Error: System.NotImplementedException System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at EnvDTE.Project.get_CodeModel() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.GetTypesAsCodeElement(Project project, CodeElement parent, String targetTypeFullName) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.Find(Project project, String targetTypeFullName) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.FindClasses(Project project) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.GetClassMap(Project project) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.Constract() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.GetFeatureElement(ICollection`1 directors) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.Constract() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.ConstractElements() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.Constract() at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.CreateCore(ISPProject project, IDirectorCreator creator) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.Create(ISPProject project) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Forms.SPToolWindow.CreateSolutions()

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using? The problem seems to be with the code not being able to call into Visual Sudio's API (EnvDTE objects are typically used in macros)

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 team suite with sp 1